# Extended Activity's Title Not Appearing With Custom Style

Tags: android, android-activity

I am overriding the Activity class in following way;

```
public class MyCustomActivity extends Activity {
 ...
 ...

}

public class MyActivity extends MyCustomActivity {
 ...
 ...

}
```

And the activity declaration in manifest is like this;

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyCustomActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity" 
    android:label = "ChildActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My problem is, the activity title defined in manifest at `android:label="ChildActivity"` is not appearing with custom style. How could I make it appear without calling `setTitle(charSeq);` in every activity?

**Edit:**

One thing (terrible thing) I forgot mentioning is that I am using custom style in following way;

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
 ...
 ...
</application>
```

**Edit (After @Mudassir's answer):**
The custom title bar layout I am using is as given below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/vector_arts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitleBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting "ChildActivity" as the label ? If yes remove the label attribute from the activity tag for MyActivity.

Comment: are you getting same title for both activites?

Comment: I am getting nothing as title? I want to achieve the default behaviour, that is when I set the `android:label` attribute in my manifest file, the title of that activity should be set without calling the method `setTitle()`.

Comment: You question don't seems to be clear, you have not added enough stuff about your query to make everyone understand.

Comment: @LalitPoptani: What you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question, you are using a text view (custom style) to show the title text. So to show the default title text (one defined in manifest at `android:label`) in you custom title bar (text view), you have to override the method `setTitle` in your parent (MyCustomActivity) as given below;

```
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence titleText) {

    // Assuming you text view's name is titleTextView in the style XML file
    TextView customTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    customTitle.setText(titleText);
}
```

then call this method from `onCreate()` of same class as follows;

`setTitle(getTitle());`

This will get the activity label defined in manifest file and pass it to the method `setTitle()` which will show it on your custom title bar that is text view (customTitle here). Note here that this approach will work only if you are using a text view to show the title text.

Comment: Thanks. Its what I want. I forgot to mention about the custom style I am using. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

You get the same title as you set in the manifest file in activity title.
if you do like this :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
     android:label="ChildActivity"
             >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TestingMyAcivity"></activity> 

public class TestingMyAcivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

}

```
public class MyActivity extends TestingMyAcivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_);
}
```

}

you get the title "ChildActivity" and layout in main_.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You are launching `MyActivity` where you have set `ChildActivity` as title. MyActivity is the child class of `MyCustomActivity`. While you set title of child class it came to the front. The activity what you are seeing is actually Child Activity not Parent. So title of ChildActivity is shown to you

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo